# How to select a Span from a same-name group based on attribute (e.g. Class)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose my HTML  has 2 Spans. They have different IDs but the same Name.

Also, Span 2 has a special Class attribute :

```
<span id="prime1" name="prime" class="someClass">..</span>
<span id="prime2" name="prime" class="someClass class2">..</span>
```

In jQuery, how do I see if **any Span with name 'Prime' contains the class "class2"**?

I was thinking of a group selector, like this, but not sure how to tweak it:

```
$('span[name="prime"]:class')
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('span.class2[name="prime"]')`? It works here - http://jsfiddle.net/6517hf48/

Comment: console.log($('.class2').attr("id")); <- this is the id that contains .class2

Comment: Josh Crozier - thanks. We can style the spans differently to make it more explicit, because right now they're both red, but I changed that jsFiddle to make 'someClass' black and 'class2' and red. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
if ( $('span[name="prime"]').hasClass('class2').length > 0 ){
   //So there's a span with name 'Prime' contains the class "class2"
}
```

Or also like @Josh Crozier mentioned in his comment :

```
if ( $('span.class2[name="prime"]').length > 0 ){
   //So there's a span with name 'Prime' contains the class "class2"
}
```

hope this helps.